# Cuda with OpenMP on Win10 using LLVM/Clang

Tags: windows, cuda, clang, openmp

I have been trying to get a simple application working that uses Cuda, OpenMP, and LLVM/Clang on Win10.  From various sources of documentation and power point presentations I've found online, I believe this functionality is supported in some manner, but I'm not sure if it's supported on Win10 and if it's in the main release.  I'm using LLVM 4.0.0rc1.  I downloaded the binary after failing to successfully build from head in various ways.

I modified this [code](https://parallel-computing.pro/index.php/9-cuda/43-openmp-4-0-on-nvidia-cuda-gpus) to look something like the following.  I've also experimented with various OMP and C variants of this.  It compiles fine.  You can see from the [verbose output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WhV7G7vocJcUpQY0M5blo4MFk/view?usp=sharing), the build appears to be making a fat binary.  Interestingly, it does not seem to care much what I give it for a target (or if I give it a target) or what specifically is in omptargets.  It will also execute cuda functions which are reported on by nvprof.

When I run this, all four of my processors go to 100% usage according to [Open Hardware Monitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/), but nothing is happening on the GPU, except maybe slight memory usage for the profiling commands.  Am I missing something, or is this just not going to work?

```
cudaError_t f;
int t = 999;
cudaProfilerStart();

printf("Enter\n");
#pragma omp target data map(tofrom: x[0:n],y[0:n]) map(tofrom: t,f)
    {
        f = cudaGetDevice(&t);
#pragma omp target teams num_teams(10) thread_limit(192)
#pragma omp parallel for
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
                y[i] += a * x[i];
                y[i] *= 2;
                y[i] -= x[i]/4;
                y[i] *= .99;
            }
        }
    }
cudaProfilerStop();
```

Output on nvprof:

```
==1844== NVPROF is profiling process 1844, command: example.exe 1000000
Enter
min = inf, max = inf, avg = 0.000000 0 0
==1844== Profiling application: example.exe 1000000
==1844== Profiling result:
No kernels were profiled.

==1844== API calls:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 98.86%  135.83ms         1  135.83ms  135.83ms  135.83ms  cudaProfilerStart
  0.60%  819.35us        91  9.0030us       0ns  398.73us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
  0.53%  726.09us         1  726.09us  726.09us  726.09us  cuDeviceGetName
  0.00%  5.2860us         1  5.2860us  5.2860us  5.2860us  cuDeviceTotalMem
  0.00%  4.5310us         1  4.5310us  4.5310us  4.5310us  cudaGetDevice
  0.00%  2.6430us         3     881ns       0ns  2.2650us  cuDeviceGetCount
  0.00%  1.5090us         3     503ns     377ns     755ns  cuDeviceGet
```

Answer (score 2):

I exchanged emails with an engineer at IBM.  Upstreaming the [fork of LLVM/Clang](https://github.com/clang-ykt/openmp) is is still in progress.  Also there is support for x86, but whether it works on Windows is unknown.

If you'll note in my link to parallel-computing.pro, there is an older fork supporting OpenMP and Cuda.  I'm not sure what, if any, the relationship between these projects is.  If you take a look at a more recent [presentation](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2016/presentation/s6240-arpith-jacob-programming-using-Openmp.pdf), it's clear that the newer fork supports OpenMP 4.0 with support coming for 4.5 and IBM is contributing in support of its Power8 CPUs.  This partially explains the uncertain support for Windows.  I searched through the code in github, however, and noted Win32 ad Win64 macros defined.